# How can I force windows 7 to manage a network adaprter and bypass the manufacturer's app?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking

I have a keebox usb wifi dongle that comes with a tsr app that I think is causing problems with the network. I understand that there's a method for forcing use of win7's native network hardware manager instead of whatever manufacturer app is provided with the device. Anyone know what it is?

Answer (score 2):

I would first **verify** that the application is the cause of the bug in the first place.

But if you are just testing, then you have a couple of options.

You can kill the manufacturer's application.

Or you can do this by uninstalling the manufacturer's application.

If that uninstalls the device driver, you'll need to reenable them.

Also, post the make and model.  It will make hunting down documentation easier.

Comment: Not really worth writing my own answer as you have pretty much said what I would - however I would say that if the network card does not have a separate driver / you are getting stuck, it is worth expanding the downloaded file and searching for `.inf` files - then, go to device manager, manually install and select the .inf ... As long as the application was not doing something required (which I have only seen a few times)this should work fine to install the driver.

Comment: Well, the uninstall is a more extreme option. Killing the app at startup just requires Autoruns.

Comment: This is a standardized technique for all nic, wired or wifi. I am trying to test the device'. So far manually enabling 811.0 g removes the manufacturer's app from the equation but there is another more formal technique that I'm trying to track down

Comment: I don't think you can get more native than Network and Sharing Center.